# SPSS: Add descriptive statistics to Likert-scale items using custom Tables

Tags: spss

I am trying to produce a table like the one depicted below using the "Custom Tables" option in SPSS.

```
                  FREQUENCIES                                                Descriptive
        Completely.Disagree    Disagree     Agree     Compl.Agree         mean  std   mode    n     
item1        count              count       count      count             
                n%               n%           n%        n%
item2        count              count       count      count
                n%               n%           n%        n%
```

I am able to produce the first part of the table (FREQUENCIES) by putting the variables as rows and the categories as columns and then selecting the summary statistics (count, n%). However, I can not find a way to put the descriptive statistics part in this table. Is there a way to do it? Or maybe combine the output of the custom tables for the FREQUENCIES PART with the descriptive statistics output using "Descriptive Statistics" option in one table?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult, because you want to two things that are not combinable in one table: 
1 You want the same category labels for different variables to be transferred to the columns
2 You want descriptives of continuous variables next to (1).

This is the closest i could come:

```
compute x=1
cta
 /vla var=x var1 disp=none
 /tab x by var1 [c][count 'Count'][layerpct 'n%'] + var1 [s][mean][mean][stddev][mode][validn]
 /sla pos=column
 /cla rowlabel=layer.
```

You would have to repeat this for every variable (var1, var2 etc) and each time take out the row with the figures you need. Furthermore, a `1` would be visible above each table and there would be an empty column on the left.

What I would suggest is making two tables: one for the counts and percentages and one for the mean, stddev etc. You would do this with:

```
cta
 /tab (var1 + var2)[c][count 'Count'][rowpct 'n%']
 /cla rowlabel=opposite
 /sla pos=row.
```

You can leave out the `/sla pos=row`, whichever you prefer.

And then the second table:

```
cta
 /tab (var1 + var2)[s][mean][stddev][mode][validn].
```

Good luck!